# Discrepancy in behavior of Contextual Outlook Add-In

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

The Contextual Outlook Add-In is behaving differently on Outlook for Mac and Outlook for Windows. The manifest file has a Regex expression as the extention point for the Add-In. Below is how it is behaving:

I have wrapped the text "CLICK TO PLAY VIDEO" with anchor tag in the email, something like below:

```
<a href="http:google.com">
    <span>CLICK TO PLAY VIDEO</span>
</a>
```

Now, the Add-In is getting triggered in Outlook for Windows but not in Outlook For MAC 2019. When I am removing the anchor around the span though, it's working fine.

The Add-In is working fine on web and outlook for windows. But, not on Outlook for Mac.

Manifest file extension point:

```
   <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="DetectedEntity">
              <Label resid="AddIn.Title" />
              <SourceLocation resid="AddIn.WebApp" />
              <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
                <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" />
                <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext" RegExName="BodyFilter" 
                    RegExValue="CLICK TO PLAY VIDEO" Highlight="all" />
              </Rule>
        </ExtensionPoint>
```

Email Content

```
    <a href="http:google.com">
       <span>CLICK TO PLAY VIDEO</span>
    </a>
```

Expected Results:
The text "CLICK TO PLAY VIDEO" should get highlighted in Outlook For MAC too, even if I am wrapping the text inside an anchor tag. Because the same thing is working fine on Outlook for Windows 2016. 
Actual Result: 
The text "CLICK HERE TO PLAY" is not getting highlighted in the Outlook For MAC 2019.